# Why is this java code working?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, iteration

During iteration, removal is not allowed from a collection. I have a piece of code that is working which i thought should not work. Can it fail in future and why is it working right now?

```
public class RemoveFromSet {

    static Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);
        set.add(3);
        set.add(4);
        while(set.size()>0) {
            int val = set.iterator().next();
            set.remove(val);
            System.out.println("removed val = "+val);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 5):

Actually this should work as your first line in the loop retrieves a brand new iterator each iteration. Now if you used the iterator after the remove you would have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you want to remove elements from a collection in a loop you use an `Iterator`. An example in your case would be:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer element = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
    System.out.println("Removed val = " + element);
}
```

As other answers have pointed out, you are getting a new iterator each loop which is why you aren't getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not an iteration of a collection. The `for` condition doesn't rely on an iterator.
The iterator created at each  inside the loop is independent of the `for` condition since created inside the loop and besides you don't iterate on that iterator : you create that at each iteration and take just first value.

It would fail if you really iterate on the collection with an iterator for example :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
    set.add(3);
    set.add(4);
    for (Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
        set.remove(integer);
        System.out.println("removed val = " + integer);
    }
  }
```